# How can I detect my client using proxy?

Tags: c#, winforms, proxy, client

I am developing a windows application. It calls a webservice. But some of my clients use a proxy. For proxy-using clients I want to show a message box and redirect to application settings WinForm for proxy credential ınfo.

So how can detect a client is using proxy? (I am using C#)

Answer (score 3):

Just check by [WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx)

```
string sampleURL = "http://proxy.example.com";
bool useProxy = !string.Equals(System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(new Uri(sampleURL)), sampleURL);    
Console.WriteLine( useProxy ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Or by simple cast check:

```
if (System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy as System.Net.WebProxy != null) {}
```

Comment: Throws en error  " Unable to cast object of type 'WebProxyWrapper' to type 'System.Net.WebProxy'. "

Comment: I have updated code. Try save cast System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy  as  System.Net.IWebProxy

Comment: (proxy != null) return true everytime.. I openeden ie and settings-connections-lan settings and ı wrote a proxy there. Your code didnt saw this change..

Comment: Fixed :) Try System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy  as  System.Net.WebProxy

Comment: Now proxy is always null? I set proxy from IE? Is this code can see this change?

Comment: Did you test like me? useproxy everytime false for me.. I opened IE and checked use proxy from connections-lan settings... And it is same it returns false.. Did you test like my test?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Did You try this code ? string sampleURL = "http://proxy.example.com";
bool useProxy = !string.Equals(System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(new Uri(sampleURL)), sampleURL);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21141/discussion-between-roman-melnyk-and-mehmetkarpuz)